# How to retrieve data from other Excel using VBA and SQL?

Tags: sql, excel, vba

I have a problem with my code. I tried retrieving data from other Excel file. My code works but I received full data in one cell (A1). I'm sorry but I'm just beginner, believe that's the problem related to output, but I'm not find out why:

```vb
Sub RefreshData()

'Refresh data

Dim CreateNew As Object
Dim RunSELECT As Object
Dim Data As String
Dim SQL As String

FolderPath = ActiveWorkbook.path

path = Left(FolderPath, InStrRev(FolderPath, "\") - 1)

Set CreateNew = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
With CreateNew
    .Provider = "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0"
    .ConnectionString = "Data Source=" & path & "\Task1.xlsm; Extended Properties=Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES;IMEX=1;CorruptLoad=xlRepairFile"
    .Open
End With

'Run SQL

SQL = "SELECT * FROM [tw$]"
Set RunSELECT = CreateNew.Execute(SQL)
Do
   output = output & RunSELECT(0) & ";" & RunSELECT(1) & ";" & RunSELECT(2) & vbNewLine
   Debug.Print RunSELECT(0); ";" & RunSELECT(1) & ";" & RunSELECT(2)
   RunSELECT.Movenext
Loop Until RunSELECT.EOF

ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Dic").Range("A1").Value = output

    RunSELECT.Close
    CreateNew.Close
    Set CreateNew = Nothing
    Set RunSELECT = Nothing

End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need to wrap recordset values wtih semicolon delimiters using a `Do` loop. Simply use [`Range.CopyFromRecordset`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.copyfromrecordset):

```vb
SQL = "SELECT * FROM [tw$]"
Set RunSELECT = CreateNew.Execute(SQL)

ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Dic").Range("A1").CopyFromRecordset RunSELECT

RunSELECT.Close
CreateNew.Close

Set CreateNew = Nothing
Set RunSELECT = Nothing
```

Comment: It works, thanks! I tried to copy headers as well, but my code doesn't work. Please could you provide a tip?

```
With RunSELECT
        For i = 1 To .Fields.Count
            ActiveSheet.Cells(1, i) = .Fields(i - 1).Name
        Next i
```

Comment: Try avoiding `ActiveSheet` and use `ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Dic")` and be sure to close context using `End With`.

Answer (score 1):

### ADOdb to Retrieve Data From Another Workbook (Without Opening It)

- While playing around with Parfait's solution combined with a few posts, I came up with the function `copySheetADOdb`.
- Adjust the constants under `Source` and `Target` in `testCopySheetADOdb` to test it.

**The Code**

```
Option Explicit

Sub testCopySheetADOdb()
    
    ' Initialize error handling.
    Const ProcName = "testCopySheetADOdb"
    On Error GoTo clearError ' Turn on error trapping.
    
    ' Source
    Const Path As String = "F:\Test"
    Const FileName As String = "Test.xlsx"
    ' Sheet Name ('SheetName') is case-insensitive i.e. 'A = a'.
    Const SheetName As String = "Sheet1"
    
    ' Target
    Const tgtName As String = "Sheet1"
    Const tgtCell As String = "A1"
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    
    ' Define FilePath.
    Dim FilePath As String
    FilePath = Path & Application.PathSeparator & FileName
    
    ' Define Target Range.
    Dim rng As Range
    Set rng = wb.Worksheets(tgtName).Range(tgtCell)
    
    ' Test Result.
    Dim Result As Boolean
    Result = copySheetADODb(rng, FilePath, SheetName)
    
    ' Of course you can do all the above in one line:
    'Result = copySheetADODB(Thisworkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1"), _
                            "C:\Test\Test.xlsx", "Sheet1")
    
    ' Inform user.
    If Result Then
        MsgBox "Worksheet successfully copied.", vbInformation, "Success"
    Else
        MsgBox "Worksheet not copied.", vbExclamation, "Failure"
    End If
        
ProcExit:
    Exit Sub

clearError:
    Debug.Print "'" & ProcName & "':" & vbLf & "    " & "Run-time error '" _
              & Err.Number & "':" & vbLf & "        " & Err.Description
    On Error GoTo 0 ' Turn off error trapping.
    GoTo ProcExit

End Sub

Function copySheetADOdb(TargetCellRange As Range, _
                        ByVal SourceFilePath As String, _
                        Optional ByVal SourceSheetName As String = "Sheet1") _
         As Boolean
    
    ' Initialize error handling.
    Const ProcName = "copySheetADOdb"
    On Error GoTo clearError ' Turn on error trapping.
    
    ' Test Target Cell Range ('TargetCellRange').
    If TargetCellRange Is Nothing Then
        GoTo NoTargetCellRange
    End If
    If TargetCellRange.Rows.Count > 1 Or TargetCellRange.Columns.Count > 1 Then
        GoTo OneCellOnly
    End If
'
    ' Define SQL Generic String.
    Const sqlGeneric As String = "SELECT * FROM [SheetName$]"
    
    Dim conn As Object
    Set conn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
    Dim strErr As String
    With conn
        .Provider = "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0"
        ' If you need the headers, HDR=NO means there are no headers
        ' (not: do not retrieve headers) so the complete data will be retrieved.
        .ConnectionString = "Data Source='" _
                          & SourceFilePath _
                          & "';" _
                          & "Extended Properties='" _
                          & "Excel 12.0 Xml;" _
                          & "HDR=NO;" _
                          & "IMEX=1;" _
                          & "CorruptLoad=xlRepairFile" _
                          & "';"
        On Error GoTo connOpenError
        .Open
            On Error GoTo clearError
            ' Run SQL.
            Dim SQL As String
            ' Replace 'SheetName' in SQL Generic String
            ' with the actual sheet name ('SourceSheetName').
            SQL = Replace(sqlGeneric, "SheetName", SourceSheetName)
            Dim rs As Object
            On Error GoTo connExecuteError
            Set rs = .Execute(SQL)
            On Error GoTo clearError
            If Not TargetCellRange Is Nothing Then
                ' Copy sheet.
                If Not rs.EOF Then
                    TargetCellRange.CopyFromRecordset rs
                    ' Write result.
                    copySheetADOdb = True
                Else
                    GoTo NoRecords
                End If
            End If
NoRecordsExit:
            rs.Close
connExecuteExit:
        .Close
    End With
    
ProcExit:
    Set rs = Nothing
    
connOpenExit:
    Set conn = Nothing

    Exit Function

NoTargetCellRange:
    Debug.Print "'" & ProcName & "': " & "No Target Cell Range ('Nothing')."
    GoTo ProcExit
    
OneCellOnly:
    Debug.Print "'" & ProcName & "': " _
              & "Target Cell Range has to be one cell range only."
    GoTo ProcExit

NoRecords:
    Debug.Print "'" & ProcName & "': No records found."
    GoTo NoRecordsExit

connOpenError:
    If Err.Number = "-2147467259" Then ' "-2147467259 (80004005)"
        strErr = "'" & SourceFilePath & "' is not a valid path"
        If Left(Err.Description, Len(strErr)) = strErr Then
            Debug.Print "'" & ProcName & "': " & strErr & "..."
            On Error GoTo 0 ' Turn off error trapping.
            GoTo connOpenExit
        End If
    Else
        GoTo clearError
    End If

connExecuteError:
    If Err.Number = "-2147467259" Then ' "-2147467259 (80004005)"
        strErr = "'" & SourceSheetName & "' is not a valid name"
        If Left(Err.Description, Len(strErr)) = strErr Then
            Debug.Print "'" & ProcName & "': " & strErr & "..."
            On Error GoTo 0 ' Turn off error trapping.
            GoTo connExecuteExit
        End If
    Else
        GoTo clearError
    End If

clearError:
    Debug.Print "'" & ProcName & "':" & vbLf & "    " & "Run-time error '" _
              & Err.Number & "':" & vbLf & "        " & Err.Description
    On Error GoTo 0 ' Turn off error trapping.
    GoTo ProcExit

End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

You have problem in this code:

```
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Dic").Range("A1").Value = output
```

you are yourself asking to save the output to A1 Cell.

I would suggest you use for or while loop to enter the data in cells according to your need.